# How to pass access token to google analytics 4 admin api

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, google-analytics-4

I'm using the PHP library for google analytics 4 admin API. But I'm unable to get the accounts list. However, I think this is because I'm not passing the auth access_token. But I'm not sure how that can be done.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Admin\V1alpha\AnalyticsAdminServiceClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\BetaAnalyticsDataClient;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\DateRange;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Dimension;
use Google\Analytics\Data\V1beta\Metric;

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=config.json');

$access_token = "**********";
$client = new AnalyticsAdminServiceClient(['access_token' => $access_token]); // is this the correct way to pass the token?
$accounts = $client->listAccountSummaries();
```

What is the correct way of accessing this API with an access token?

My json file have below credentials,

```
{
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "**********************",
    "private_key_id": "**********************",
    "private_key": "**********************",
    "client_email": "**********************.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
    "client_id": "**********************",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "*******************"
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you send request using php cURL to `https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1alpha/accountSummaries?access_token=XXX`

Comment: Why would you want to access it with an access token using the PHP library the whole point of the library is it is able to fetch its own tokens as needed using your credentials.

Comment: @DaImTo But why I'm not getting the account lists using this API? it should return my accounts and its property.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be applying the access token you should let the client library fetch its own.

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Admin\V1alpha\AnalyticsAdminServiceClient;

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/path/to/service-account.json');

$client = new AnalyticsAdminServiceClient();

$accounts = $client->listAccounts();

foreach ($accounts as $account) {
    print 'Found account: ' . $account->getName() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

[php-analytics-admin#sample](https://github.com/googleapis/php-analytics-admin#sample)

Comment: I have tried the above and the response is blank. Am I doing anything wrong? I have edited my question with config file parameters.

Comment: Does the service account have access to any google analytics accounts?   [User doesn't have any google analytics accounts easy solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0fwl7tbS8U)

Comment: Thank you very much..!! This resolved my issue. I don't have enough reputation to upvote the answer.

Comment: My website already has universal analytics and now we are upgrading to GA4. In universal analytics, we were fetching the profiles, and based on the profile we were fetching the analytics data like new users, sessions, page views, organic search, and referrals. But I'm not sure how this thing I'll be able to collect in GA4. Does property in GA4 same like as the profile of universal analytics? I need to use reporting API to collect the pageview and session etc?

Comment: Google analytics admin api, is like the management api was with UA, it gave you access to profile data.    The Google analytics data api, is like the google analytics reporting api.  It gives you access to the data in the account.

Comment: This is your question you should have the rep to accept the answer if it helped you.